# Inserting the looped data into sql

Tags: sql, xpath

I'm trying to scrape some data with xpath and then inserting into SQL.

Echo is working fine but when inserting into sql, it only gets the first line.

Example:

```
    <?php 
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT table.title, table.link FROM table WHERE table.link LIKE 'http://www.%' AND streams.title = ''");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
      $html = new DOMDocument();
      @$html->loadHtmlFile($row["link"]);
      $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

      foreach ($xpath->query("//table[@style='margin-left: 5px;']//td[@width='150']//a") as $files)
      {
        $html = new DOMDocument();
        @$html->loadHtmlFile($files->getAttribute('href'));
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

        $hl = $xpath->query("//div[@style='width:742px']/a[preceding-sibling::div[@id='help1']]/@href")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $link=serialize(array('link' => $hl));
        $link=sqlesc($link); 
        echo $link; // all lines gets printed, thats okay?
        mysql_query("UPDATE streams SET streams.hl=$link") or die(mysql_error()); // Only first line gets inserted, why?
      }

    }  
    ?>
```

Comment: your UPDATE statment do not have WHERE clausule, that sounds like a problem ...

Comment: I also tried with the WHERE clausule and still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are updating all rows , and you get all rows containing the same data because last update updates all the rows , do you want to update an existing rows or just insert new rows ?

if you want to insert try this

```
INSERT INTO streams (hl) VALUES ($link)
```

if there is others non-optional columns in the table , insert those values also